# put different column names in separate columns in csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a dataframe that has such data:

```
{0: {'ID': 0, 'ParentID': 0, 'MapCode': 0},
 1: {'ID': 1, 'ParentID': 1, 'MapCode': 0},
 2: {'ID': 2, 'ParentID': 2, 'MapCode': 0},
 3: {'ID': 3, 'ParentID': 3, 'MapCode': 0},
 4: {'ID': 4, 'ParentID': 4, 'MapCode': 0}}
```

I save the df as a csv like this.

```
df.to_csv("./file.csv", index=False)
```

Although the df appears normally in my notebook, it seems to be messed up when I open the saved csv through Excel. There are commas showing. It appears like this

[image]

This causes problems because if I try to use this dataset with hyperAPI, it gives me an error message that columns are too few. It should be like this instead:

[image]

How can I fix my original dataframe that it gets saved in the correct format, such that all column names appear separately in separate columns?

Comment: I think the issues could be coming for the Excel side. Could you try [setting the Excel to read CSV file with commas as delimiters](https://support.affinity.co/hc/en-us/articles/360044453711-How-to-open-CSV-files-with-the-correct-delimiter-separator)?

Comment: Or you could use [`df.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)?

Comment: I need a csv to be used later. I tried saving an excel and then reading it again , and then converting it into a csv again but the final result is still the same, even tho excel format was fine @Ch3steR

Comment: @user696969 to follow this, I would need to opt for the utf8 encoding, which will again cause problems in hyperAPI. It shouldn't be saving the csv like this in the first place

Comment: Could you update your question with the code you used for passing the CSV file to hyperAPI and the exact error message it gave? I think this might be a separated issue to the Excel reading CSV file

Answer (score 0):

try this code it works fine for me

```
 data = {'ID': ['0', '1', '2', '3','4'], 'ParentID': [0, 1, 2, 3,4],'MapCode':[0,0,0,0,0]}
 df = pd.DataFrame(data)
 print(df)
 df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Comment: nah, it still opens it in the same way on Excel for me

Comment: i think it is a problem in your excel